# How to get links file for all URLs of ASTER AG100?

Tags: url, aster, nasa

I need to write up a simple program that inputs a URL link and yields the relevant image for [AG100](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/ASTT/). I want to avoid having to download an entire database worth of AG100 h5 files and just pull what I need via URL link.

I notice [LP DAAC](https://git.earthdata.nasa.gov/projects/LPDUR/repos/daac_data_download_python/browse?_gl=1*151x69x*_ga*MjAzMDgwMzI3Ni4xNjg3ODM3MDI4*_ga_0YWDZEJ295*MTY4NzgzNzAyOS4xLjEuMTY4Nzg0MjA4NS4wLjAuMA..) provides code to access the relevant image if you have the respective URL, and further elaborates that if you so wish you can create "download a Links File (containing URLs to files) from a NASA Earthdata Search Client request for data." I looked at NASA Earthdata for the AG100 ASTER data, and could not find a means of downloading into a .txt or .xml file all the relevant links found in AG100 for every h5 file.

Does anyone know what LP DAAC is talking about with the so-called Links File you can generate from NASA Earthdata Search Client. Or does anyone know of a way to quickly generate a .txt file of all .h5 urls for AG100?